# Instragram App Permission Declined

Tags: ios, permissions, instagram, instagram-api, permission-denied

In last November, we took permission for our app on Instagram developer website and we made it live after completing full app life cycle.

But recently, we faced issue in Instagram login by saying app authentication required and we tried to take permission again. But, we aren't able to because we are getting app review revert "App can't be replicate of Instagram. Permission denied."

I am seriously not getting the reason behind it. 
can somebody suggest me what shall I do now ? My App is live and facing this problem.

Thank you so much In advance.

Comment: looks like you created replica app of Instagram and they don't want to allow you to do this...so, removed your permission to get auth from Instagram. .....

Comment: you need to mail Instagram support team and explain what is different in your app and why you need Instagram

Comment: Yes @DarshitShah.
 I will try to mail them.

Comment: Can you share the email ID in case you know it ?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/

Comment: did they email you with warning or just revoked your app without notice ?

Comment: They revoked it without notice.

Comment: @DarshitShah I have already checked it.. but no email-ID in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login here : http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/
[image]
Report your issue from Dashboard